# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess incredibly slow performance on Parent-Children complex object

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

There is a complex object that contains couple of children objects.
if populate each of them separately, for example, in the C# **Unit Test** performance of Oracle DB is very good , each request from C# to Oracle DB takes **20-40 ms** to complete. But if combine these classes/objects to "parent" object as children, the performance dramatically decreased. There is a log below populated by dotTrace. 
In the program exists **ConnectionManager** that returns the **OracleConnection** object. If there is  couple of requests, it does not close the connection but returns existing one. If there is no requsts it closes the connection
It shows very good performance in unit test for individual objects. 
It looks like **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** does not work "async" and if we have couple of requests at the same time these requests "hangs" in a queue...
Is it make sense to create a **pool** of opened Oracle Connections (3-4) and keep all of them alive and dynamically return one of them to a requester , mark it "is in use", return next one that is NOT "is in use" for next request etc? 
Will it increase performance of the database calls ?
will it be "async" ? Or  anyway Oracle.ManagedDataAccess will work in a "sync" mode and every conenction will wait until another connection returns a resultset?

```
15,80 %   Open  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open
  15,80 %   Get  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString, PM, ConnectionString, SecureString, SecureString, OracleConnection)
    15,80 %   Get  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString, Boolean, OracleConnection, String, Boolean)
      15,80 %   Get  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString, Boolean, OracleConnection, String, Boolean)
        15,80 %   CreateNewPR  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.CreateNewPR(Int32, Boolean, ConnectionString, OracleConnection, String, List)
          15,80 %   CreateNewPR  •  1 754 ms  •  1 call  •  OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32, Boolean, ConnectionString, OracleConnection, String, List)
            15,80 %   Wait  •  1 753 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(Int32, CancellationToken)
              0,00 %   UpdateStateAtomically  •  0 ms  •  2 calls  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.UpdateStateAtomically(Int32, Int32)
              0,00 %   get_IsSet  •  0 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.get_IsSet
              0,00 %   EnsureLockObjectCreated  •  0 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.EnsureLockObjectCreated
              0,00 %   Dispose  •  0 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose
              0,00 %   set_Waiters  •  0 ms  •  2 calls  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.set_Waiters(Int32)
              0,00 %   ThrowIfDisposed  •  0 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.ThrowIfDisposed
              0,00 %   InternalRegisterWithoutEC  •  0 ms  •  1 call  •  System.Threading.CancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC(Action, Object)
            0,00 %   8 functions hidden  •  0 ms total  •  10 calls total
          0,00 %   2 functions hidden  •  0 ms total  •  2 calls total
        0,00 %   13 functions hidden  •  0 ms total  •  14 calls total
    0,00 %   2 functions hidden  •  0 ms total  •  2 calls total
  0,00 %   20 functions hidden  •  0 ms total  •  32 calls total

#stacktrace
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incude a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for your Oracle table(s); details of any indexes, triggers, etc. that may affect performance; a minimal example of the the C# that is causing the issue; and the execution plan for the queries (if the problem is on the Oracle side rather than a C# issue). Trying to debug the performance of something without having any code is an (almost) impossible task.

Comment: @MTO thank you for quick response. Problem is not at Oracle DB side. There is 5 "chilren" aka C#-classes that combined into big "Parent" class. Every "child" show very good performance when it tested separately in the unit test. Every SQL view/package/procedure works very fine. Response time is 20-40 ms. But, in case of real-world case when there are couple of C# (or native) threads that are sending requests to Oracle DB by trying to use THE SAME opened OracleConenction objects, seems all threads and all objects "hanging" while another thread/object completes it request to DB

Comment: It looks like when a connection is first added to the pool there is an initial connection time of 754ms.  What is the AVERAGE time of each query?

Comment: Does it mean that OracleConnection object from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess works works exclusively with only one thread (object)? Are the other thread (objects) waiting for a connection to be released from another thread/object?
Does this mean that we have to create a new OracleConnection for every thread for better performance?
but, will Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll run each opened connection in parallel? Or, anyway, will it be synchronous? and each connection will wait for others connection completes their work?

Comment: @jdweng 20-40ms if initiliaze the connection , and then  run the unit test for each "child" separately. But in the real world we already have opened connection, it is already initialized , so, the 20-40 ms * 5 = 100- 200 ms is expected for  5 "children" , But instead it looks like a "child" waiting while another "child" completes the request, But these "children" populates in a 5 different threads, So it could take maximun 40 ms to complete

Comment: The log file isn't clearly showing what is causing the delay.  Is it the actual query or something in the c# code?  You need to get the time of the actual database query and not the c# code.